# version solving failed. Pubspec yaml, flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, pubspec, anyline

Because every version of anyline depends on permission_handler ^5.0.1+1 and motorgate depends on permission_handler ^8.3.0, anyline is forbidden.
So, because motorgate depends on anyline ^24.0.0-dev.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because motorgate depends on anyline ^24.0.0-dev.1, version solving failed.)

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.4
  json_annotation: ^4.3.0
  flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
  provider: ^6.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  material_design_icons_flutter: 5.0.5955-rc.1
  start_jwt: ^0.2.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  flutter_pw_validator: ^1.3.0
  cool_alert:
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.4
  whatsapp_unilink: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.15
  flutter_launch: ^0.3.0
  geolocator: ^7.7.1
  geocoding: ^2.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.1
  flutter_facebook_auth:
  flutter_animated_dialog: ^2.0.1
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
  restart_app: ^1.1.0
  permission_handler: ^8.3.0
  anyline: ^24.0.0-dev.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to use dependency override.

Answer (score 0):

`anyline` is outdated and not compatible with your other packages. You would have to downgrade `permission_handler` to version `^5.0.1+1` to be compatible, but this could cause other problems.